# Select most frequent values alongside with sum

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to find most frequent product each Employee has sold alongside with product with most income. I wrote some example to be more clearfull.

```
DECLARE @Products TABLE(ID INT, ProductName NVARCHAR(50), Price DECIMAL)
DECLARE @Employees TABLE(ID INT, EmployeeName NVARCHAR(50))
DECLARE @Sales TABLE(ID INT, EmployeeID INT, ProductID INT, Quantity INT)

INSERT INTO @Products VALUES
(1, N'Product1', 300),
(2, N'Product2', 500),
(3, N'Product3', 700),
(4, N'Product4', 800)

INSERT INTO @Employees VALUES
(1, N'Employee1'),
(2, N'Employee2'),
(3, N'Employee3')

INSERT INTO @Sales VALUES
(1,1,2,3),
(2,1,3,4),
(3,1,2,5),
(4,2,2,7),
(5,2,4,3),
(6,3,2,3),
(7,3,2,9),
(8,3,4,8)
```

The joined tables looks likes this:

[image]

I wrote some select

```
SELECT
     e.EmployeeName
    ,p.ProductName
    ,SUM(s.Quantity) AS Quantity    
    ,p.ProductName
    ,SUM(s.Quantity * p.Price) AS Price
FROM @Products p
    INNER JOIN @Sales s ON s.ProductID = p.ID
    INNER JOIN @Employees e ON s.EmployeeID = e.ID
GROUP BY e.EmployeeName, p.ProductName
ORDER BY SUM(s.Quantity) DESC, SUM(s.Quantity * p.Price)
```

which returns this result, which is not correct. You note that price is not ordered
[image]

I want write select in this format, order ProductName and Sum of Quantity, ProductName and Sum of Price for each Employe separately.

Expected output should be

```
EmployeeName        ProductName    Quantity    ProductName      Price
------------        -----------    --------    -----------      ------
Employee3           Product2       12          Product4         6400
Employee1           Product2       8           Product2         4000     
Employee3           Product4       8           Product2         6000
Employee2           Product2       7           Product2         3500
Employee1           Product3       4           Product3         2800
Employee2           Product4       3           Product4         2400
```

Comment: I believe Quantity and Price is ordered according to your select statement. First order by Quantity descending, then order by Price ascending.

Comment: Please post expected output as well

Comment: @NickyvV yes but Price is not ordered ascending anyway

Comment: @Suraz I edited post

Comment: I think that not possible

Comment: I'm sorry, I just redited again correctly expected output table

Answer (score 0):

Your query is the beginning.  Then you can use window functions and conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT EmployeeName,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum_q = 1 THEN ProductName END) as productname_q,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum_q = 1 THEN Quantity END) as quantity_q,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum_pq = 1 THEN ProductName END) as productname_pq,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum_pq = 1 THEN Quantity END) as quantity_pq
FROM (SELECT e.EmployeeName, p.ProductName,
             SUM(s.Quantity) AS Quantity, SUM(s.Quantity * p.Price) AS Price,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e.EmployeeName
                                ORDER BY SUM(s.Quantity) DESC
                               ) as seqnum_q,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e.EmployeeName
                                ORDER BY SUM(s.Quantity * p.Price) DESC
                               ) as seqnum_pq
      FROM @Products p INNER JOIN
           @Sales s
           ON s.ProductID = p.ID INNER JOIN
           @Employees e
           ON s.EmployeeID = e.ID
      GROUP BY e.EmployeeName, p.ProductName
     ) ep
GROUP BY EmployeeName;
```

Comment: This query returns only 3 rows

Comment: @www1986 . . . I see you edited the question to provide sample output.  This returns one row for each employee, which seems more in the spirit of the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Order BY To:

```
ORDER BY SUM(s.Quantity) DESC, SUM(s.Quantity * p.Price) Desc
```

Comment: still same problem

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT
     e.EmployeeName
    ,p.ProductName
    ,SUM(s.Quantity) AS Quantity    
    ,p.ProductName
    ,SUM(s.Quantity * p.Price) AS Price
FROM @Sales s
    INNER JOIN @Products p  ON s.ProductID = p.ID
    INNER JOIN @Employees e ON s.EmployeeID = e.ID

GROUP BY e.EmployeeName, p.ProductName
ORDER BY e.EmployeeName, SUM(s.Quantity) DESC, SUM(s.Quantity * p.Price),p.ProductName
```

Comment: Please correct the error by changing FROM clause so it will be executable

Comment: @suraz sorry by mistake i was testing few scenarios and forgot products after sales s